# fwrite prints garbage, fread reads garbage structures

Tags: c, struct, fwrite, fread

I was testing out binary file i/o. So, to practice I made a small program:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "person.h"

int main()
{
    struct person me;
    struct person cpy_me;
    FILE *dataWrite, *dataRead;

    strcpy(me.fname, "john");
    strcpy(me.lname, "smith");
    me.age = 12;

    printf("%s %s %d\n", me.fname, me.lname, me.age);

    dataWrite = fopen("people.bin", "wb");
    if (fwrite(&me, sizeof( struct person), 1, dataWrite) != 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Error!\n");
    printf("Wrote to the file\n");

    dataRead = fopen("people.bin", "rb");

    fread(&cpy_me, sizeof(struct person), 1, dataRead);
    printf("%s->Fname\n", cpy_me.fname);
    printf("%s->Lname\n", cpy_me.lname);
    printf("%d->Age\n", cpy_me.age);

    fclose(dataWrite);
    fclose(dataRead);

    return 0;
}
```

person.h:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H_INCLUDED
#define PERSON_H_INCLUDED

#define   MAXFIRST    10
#define   MAXLAST     20

struct person
{
    char lname[MAXLAST], fname[MAXFIRST];
    int age;
};
#endif // PERSON_H_INCLUDED
```

This is what appeared in the file `people.bin`:

```
smith ÿÿb¸tÄ[½tà@ john @ à@
```

When I read displayed the results of `fread`, I got:

[image]

I know that in binary files, it doesn't display it in a human readable form, but is it supposed to look like this? I don't think so, because the age isn't even visible, and `fread` is showing that it read garbage.

Comment: `fclose(data);data=fopen("people.bin", "rb");fread(&cpy_me,...`

Comment: Now i get this: `smith ÿÿb¸tÄ[½tà@ john @ à@    `

Comment: `fclose(dataWrite);` move before `dataRead = fopen("people.bin", "rb");`.  re-open it after the file closed.

Comment: Age shouldn't be visible--the integer 12 will probably be written as a byte of value 12 and three bytes of 0, none of which is printable. Also, you allocated fixed amounts of space for each name. Whatever bytes happen to be in memory beyond the length of the actual name will appear in the output, and they could be anything. Try displaying the file with something like "od" (or whatever the Windows equivalent is--I know nothing about Windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet has two separate problems: First, as BLUEPIXY already commented, you need to either close and reopen, or rewind the file, before reading it in again. Otherwise your `fread()` fails, and since this is not checked for errors in your program, you won't notice until you try to print the strings inside `cpy_me`, which have remained uninitialized.

This gets to problem number two: make sure to initialize struct `me` to zeros, e.g. by doing `struct person me = {"", "", 0};` This should take care of the garbage you see in your binary file. Structs in C are not automatically initialized unless they are globals or you explicitly tell the compiler to do so.

As an aside: Note that doing binary I/O like this is non-portable, since the structs may have a different memory layout on different architectures (to see this, try recompiling in 32 and 64-bit mode and compare the binary files your program generates).